# How to redirect to same uri and domain with different port

Tags: nginx

This is the current rule:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com.br$request_uri;
}
```

It redirects all requests on `http` port to `https`. 
But now, it need to redirect to https with any subdomain.

I tried this, but it redirects to localhost:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Use `$host` instead of `$server_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```